Jenkins run cuucmber test with tags
I have feature file like:
Feature: user booking services

  Scenario Outline: 1 user booking one service successfully
    Given login as a new user 
    When select location "Toronto" and confirm
    And select service "Biometric Screening" and confirm
    And select date "<preferDate>"
    And select time "<preferTime>" then confirm
    And confirm the oppointment
    Then the oppointment should confirmed and showing booked service like following
         | Biometric Screening  |  <bookingResult> |
    
    @regress
    Examples:
    | preferDate | preferTime | bookingResult   |
    | 2024-05-31 | 11:40 AM   | 31-May-2024 11:40 AM - 12:00 PM |
        
    Examples:
    | preferDate | preferTime | bookingResult   |
    | 2024-05-30 | 09:00 AM   | 30-May-2024 09:00 AM - 09:20 AM |
    | 2024-05-21 | 04:40 PM   | 21-May-2024 04:40 PM - 05:00 PM |

And have configuration in Jenkins:
enter image description here
enter image description here
But, all scenarios were running, not only @regress scenario.
Console of output of jenkins show:
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\VF\FE-BDD\pom.xml test -Dcucumber.options=--tags @regress

also tried
test -Dcucumber.filter.tags = "@regress"

doesn't work
